# How do I set the chunkname of a Lua chunk?

Tags: lua, chunks

I'm currently using the C API call `luaL_loadstring()` to load a chunk, but this call doesn't have a way of naming the chunk.

Is there a way of naming a chunk after it's loaded?

Alternatively, I see the `lua_load()` function takes a chunkname parameter, but I haven't found any examples of how to use it: How can I replace a `luaL_loadstring()` call with `lua_load()`?

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `luaL_loadbuffer(L,s,strlen(s),name)`.